# Trivial JSON jackson polymorphic deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Struggling with something which looks like trivial and should work without any problems. I have JSON with "@class" property and without knowing it's class on the moment of invocation readValue() want to deserialize it into the object of the class referenced by "@class". What I get back instead is "LinkedHashMap".

```
@Test
public void toJsonAndBack() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Sample("id"));
    assertTrue(json.contains("@class"));
    Sample obj = (Sample)mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
static class Sample {
    private String id;

    public Sample() {
    }

    public Sample(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Sorry, if dup, but couldn't find exactly the same problem. The most of people have more complicated cases where there is base class, which is also annotated, etc. These cases actually work fine.

I'm using jackson 2.6.6

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but the right idiom for de-serializing would simply be `Sample obj = mapper.readValue(json, Sample.class);`, no casting.

Comment: @Mena In reality, of course, case is a bit more complicated, that is just example to illustrate the desired behavior. I can't use type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson converts it into `LinkedhashMap`, so that later, we can you use its convert method to convert given `LinkedhashMap` into custom Object. So here you need to add one more step into it.

E.g:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Sample("id"));
Object obj = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
Sample sample = mapper.convertValue(obj, Sample.class);
```

So you can preserve this obj somewhere, and can convert it into `Sample` class at your convenience.

Comment: Thx, that is workable. I can read "@class" property from the map, get the class and pass it into convertValue(). I just was hoping to leave all that plumbing for jackson handle.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently adding this line makes this test work:

```
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
```

In that case annotation on the Sample class is not necessary.